# Javascript behaves differently when served by an Azure instance whereas the same from AWS works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, azure, amazon-web-services

I have got this weird problem with a javascript code that does not seem to work when it is served from an Azure instance. There is another server hosted in AWS which serves the same request and the resulting javascript works as expected. I will post the gist of the script below however to make it easier for anyone trying to help, the base problem is around reading a "Data" attribute named "usr-voucher-code" on the html element and it does not work on the browser when the resulting javascript was served as a result of a request that hit the Azure instance.

```html
<a href="#" class="btn remove-voucher" data-name="Double Garlic Bread &amp; 1.25L Drink" data-order-item-id="5" data-usr-voucher-code="123456" title="Remove Voucher">remove</a>
```

The javascript file that uses the "data-usr-voucher-code" above is minified during the bundling process and the resultant scripts for AWS and Azure are shown below:

### Azure

```html
require(["common/myBanners"], s),
        e(".remove-product").click(function(t) {
            var a, n, s, l, m, h, f;
            return f = e(this).data("voucher-code"),
            a = e(this).data("order-item-id"),
            s = e(this).data("name"),
            h = e(this).attr("data-product-code"),
            l = e(".basket-product").length,
            n = r.productRemoved,
            m = function(o) {
                null == o.messages && (n = n.replace("[name]", s),
                n = n.replace("[number]", l - 1),
                e("#basket-aria-message").text(n));
                var t = function() {
                    "undefined" != typeof d && d.isSomeCallBack && i.RemoveSelectedlogo({
                        productCode: h,
                        voucherCode: f,
                        url: d.getSelectedProd
                    })
                };
                v(o, t)
            }
```

### AWS

```html
require(["common/myBanners"], c),
        e(".remove-product").click(function(t) {
            var a, n, c, d, u, h, f;
            f = e(this).data("voucher-code"),
            a = e(this).data("order-item-id"),
            c = e(this).data("name"),
            h = e(this).attr("data-product-code"),
            d = e(".basket-product").length,
            n = r.productRemoved,
            u = function(o) {
                null == o.messages && (n = n.replace("[name]", c),
                n = n.replace("[number]", d - 1),
                e("#basket-aria-message").text(n));
                var t = function() {
                   "undefined" != typeof d && d.isSomeCallBack && 
                   i.RemoveSelectedlogo({
                        productCode: h,
                        voucherCode: f,
                        url: l.getSelectedProd
                    })
                };
                p(o, t)
            }
```

**My issue is basically around the following:**

```html
AWS:
e(".remove-product").click(function(t) {
            var a, n, c, d, u, h, f;
            f = e(this).data("voucher-code"),

Azure:
e(".remove-product").click(function(t) {
            var a, n, s, l, m, h, f;
            **return f** = e(this).data("voucher-code"),
            a = e(this).data("order-item-id"),
```

Many thanks for your time and patience, chers.

Comment: "_it does not work on the browser when the resulting javascript was served_" - so, what's the problem? Are you getting errors in the Console? Post them!